# adding current time in column while inserting mysql

Tags: mysql, database

So I have this table

```
create table c_order(
    order_date         date               not null,
    order_id           number,
    customer_id        number             not null,
    product_id         number             not null,
    primary key (order_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references Customer(customer_id),
    foreign key (product_id) references products(product_id)
);
```

where customers order for a product.

Now I want it be such that when a data is entered using `'Insert into'` then we need not insert the date rather it will be automatically saved to current data. Should I change `create table` structure for that or use a trigger? What is the syntax then? In trigger is it before/after insert?

Comment: set the default value of the column to current time. an example you should find by using google

Comment: Study for default values of columns

Comment: sorry to inform default values cannot be used for date datatype.. as I anticipated I have to use trigger here... my question was should it be before/after.. the answer is before... thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer..

Default is not going to work here since the data type is date and functions cannot be used for putting default values in date datatype (for timestamp it can be done).

The answer is trigger.  The code is (for oracle.. for mysql sysdate() should be changed to now() )

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER auto_insert_date BEFORE INSERT ON c_order
    FOR EACH ROW 
    begin
    :NEW.order_date := sysdate();
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

```
create table c_order(
    order_date         TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    order_id           number,
    customer_id        number             not null,
    product_id         number             not null,
    primary key (order_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references Customer(customer_id),
    foreign key (product_id) references products(product_id)
);
```

Comment: I need datatype date as I am not using time here, just date.

Comment: Just change the datatype to date, it will truncate the timestamp part off, leaving only the date part.